# Vue - how to animate table row change

Tags: vue.js

I have animation working on a table when new rows are added or rows are removed.

But I'd like to animate rows that *change* - they aren't added or deleted, but the data bound to that row changes.

Is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to [transition state](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitioning-state.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either look at transitioning the state as @craig_h suggests or perhaps just set up a regular javascript event that watches for animation end.

To utilise the second method you could add a new param `changed: false` to each rows data, then set this to true when it is changed. This could then add a class to the row of 'changed'. Then have your CSS fire an animation when the row has the 'changed' class. Now all you need to do is listen for the 'animationend' event on that row and reset the changed param to false. Something like:

**html - row element**

```
<table>
  <tr
    ref="rows"
    :class="{ changed: row.changed }"
    v-for="(row, index) in rows">
    <td><input v-model="row.title" type="text"></td>
    <td>
      <button @click="saveRowEdits(index)">save</button>
    </td>
    ...
```

**component**

```
data () {
  return {
    rows: [
      { title: 'foo', changed: false },
      { title: 'bar', changed: false },
    ],
    ...
  }
},
methods: {
  saveRowEdits (index) {

    // get the rows DOM el
    const row = this.$refs.rows[index]

    // watch for animationend
    const callback = () => {
      row.removeEventListener("animationend", callback);
      this.rows[index].changed = false
    }

    row.addEventListener("animationend", callback, false)

    // update param
    this.rows[index].changed = true

  },
  ...
```

**CSS**

```
row.changed {
  animation: changed-row 1s ...
```

Comment: This sounds like a good method. The rows are actually rendered from a massive object full of objects. What I might do is have a simple 'changedRows' array, and on the computed class check whether this row is in that array. Thanks for the help.

Comment: yeah, adjust to suit your needs of course. Glad to help